# How to make ripples more visible?

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I am looking to make the jQuery ripples effect more visible on a background colour instead of an image.

https://codepen.io/glittergirl/pen/LJmKWw
In this example you can see how the ripple is barely visible so I am looking for a way to change the colour / contrast of the ripple effect so it looks like a coloured liquid

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('section').ripples();
})
```

This uses the jquery ripples plugin from: https://github.com/sirxemic/jquery.ripples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply very high contrast to the canvas that it uses for drawing:

```
.jquery-ripples canvas { filter: contrast(1000%); }
```

Forked Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dqKMZg

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('section').ripples({
        perturbance : 0.9
   });
});
```

Try this.